# Cannot send more than one command to console application

Tags: c#, .net, process, stream, console

I have a problem when communicating with console application using the `Process` class.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"consoleApp.exe";        
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Process = Process.Start(psi);
Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

What I need is to write commands to console, retrieve answers, respond to them. But, a command that is sent to console works only if I close the stream:

```
Process.StandardInput.WriteLine("command");
Process.StandardInput.Close();
```

Why is it so? After this, of course, I cannot communicate with console app again. What am I doing wrong? How can I normally communicate with console application? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a slippery slope, I'd try to approach it differently but if you must interact in such a way, you could perhaps try:

```
Process.StandardInput.Flush();
```

instead of Close();  only Close() and dispose everything once you're completely finished.

Comment: I tried. It did not work. I read somewhere that it only relevant for output streams.

Comment: But there is no moment when I completely can finish. I need to communicate with the program constantly (it is a external Sip caller).

Comment: I've not done exactly what you're after, but in theory it should work, and write to the standard input.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx  If we're writing to a file stream for example, calling flush would ensure that anything in the buffer is immediately written.

Comment: How are you determining if it "works" or not?  Is this the rough example you're following?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx

Comment: I am connecting to the Sip server using the command. I can see on the server whether I am connected or not.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd, so you're debugging it and you only see the connection on the Sip end after you step through the Close() line, not the WriteLine("command")?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a StreamWriter as described in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx

When creating two console apps, one with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n = 0;
        while (n < 5)
        {
            var line = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Read line {0}: {1}", n, line);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

And one with the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ConsoleApplication1.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        myProcess.Start();

        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;

        var n = 0;
        while (n < 5)
        {
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine("line" + n.ToString());
            n++;
        }

        myStreamWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Read line 0: line0
Read line 1: line1
Read line 2: line2
Read line 3: line3
Read line 4: line4
```

Comment: They close StreamWriter. But I cannot do the same, because I will need it to establish further communication with an application.

Comment: Sorry, should have made that clearer, but you can do multiple WriteLine's and they get accepted as separate inputs. Will update the answer.

Comment: So, I should avoid using Process.BeginOutputReadLine()?

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't used the asynchronous methods yet; maybe it works if you call BeginOutputReadLine multiple times, but I imagine you will then have to have some call back in place in order to know when to do that.